# "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1" in Xamarin

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

This error appears when trying to view the Main.axml in Visual Studio. It's a new, untouched Xamarin android project. This happens with every .axml file I try to view in the designer.

[image]
My XML is valid, as far as I can tell, and I have not changed it in any way. There are no strange characters to be found when inspecting the file.

[image]

Interestingly, even in a fresh project, it says "The 'LinearLayout' element is not declared". I wouldn't expect that to cause an issue at the root level, but it may be a hint.

I am able to compile this default app to android, but I am more interested in actually editing it. How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the correct Android SDK location in Xamarin Preferences?

Comment: Yes, I have. It compiles to android, which wouldn't be possible without the sdk.

Comment: Have you tried to repair your vs, and update your xamarin.android to the latest stable version? This looks like an environment issue to me, normally vs can map your `LinearLayout` with the android-layout-xml.xsd file for example under the path "YourProjectPath\obj\Debug\Schemas\23".